# HttpWebRequest Http Headers

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm using HttpWebRequest component and trying to POST data to server.
When I use browser I can trace that it sends this request

```
POST https://plus.google.com/_/socialgraph/mutate/modifymemberships/?_reqid=1950158&rt=j HTTP/1.1
Host: plus.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
X-Same-Domain: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
Referer: https://plus.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/home/b,s/rt=h/ver=OeD97kiQfn8.en./sv=1/am=!iPoVWvyH1UcKPT9bc1pNSZLcSj8oHAelto24gJorhwk/d=1/
Content-Length: 216
Cookie: PREF=ID=c42cff62752fc3e8:U=dae37ffa177e0689:FF=0:TB=2:LD=en:CR=2:TM=1244434765:LM=1311323210:DV=0SJoub_nzRUL:GM=1:S=EuE8opfqNl8PGGHI; NID=54=enDovqVn7CSHrPtZ2ZSPAt4PrE0ZZE-rWJawva2NiUWC1TzreG-sVdiSnRp7kolqcvMCGCIKt7agHKT6Hi2JZkV5qYmY_fUkxFjk6PUc7TrdNRAT7_9mRnvwOxeBOcng; rememberme=false; __utma=1.340991765.1324442547.1324723420.1324806933.8; __utmz=1.1324723420.7.7.utmcsr=google.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/accounts/Logout2; OTZ=1044056_4_4_133320_8_385320; S=analytics-realtime-frontend=h23QCGj_I9O7FLG9cqDjkA:awfe=SnIt_U1wxuihQ1myCwuiZA:awfe-efe=lCXLSEuiUzX3HyaRuXVuRg:adwords-optimization=yCZeLrx1FD0uGQFYb07LTQ:adwords-common-ui=WfNukVX7rVpTuVtMlZ6IbA; S_awfe=tyb6VRVQyBHkv8nbfMNWRg; GMAIL_RTT=571; __utmc=1; HSID=AtaMO-oLk9-OMZkiv; SSID=AGt3gDSdd3Q98pA81; APISID=7xRgosYs7uOXzd0Y/AI4OXaHRTViR8oE8s; SAPISID=0HNI_ffNupNL-UfT/Ao6YbG5vkEashPdOM; ULS=EgYKBBICZW4Yy-Xb9wQ; SID=DQAAALMAAADk5OelxcPoQKO8FrSoOfOGoTHX4HeVfeJJQhtd19k07mJMUhJkiehF1FTzb7jNt34c80UGpyXEJT5FML373p6RR_5EQ3etVYjUXmgqHsdO7G-XuP_k_m798MDvd4AWkDX2vKVtqc5zA_olxB9UkJBLU_g2IM2vZ3Scp-eThZj8C3uZuzdN_DCpQeVjrU6a1kiIdQRsz9rUtxzoC0E22Ux4ba0QneaWBT73Ns14wh7fqZtYB-DRB2zcWkXXoNnV67U; FBS_VI_1324806859_0=ot_00Qg-hkQV7uhIEb0dTMT0_DD6aAI
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

a=%5B%5B%5B%225947b6d78a8231f3%22%5D%5D%5D&m=%5B%5B%5B%5Bnull%2Cnull%2C%22113690702042497323038%22%5D%2C%22Stephanie%20Parker%22%2C%5B%5D%5D%5D%5D&r=%5B%5B%5D%5D&at=AObGSAg06IXl5iYSceecKRc64xHVAB_GDw%3A1324806859000&
```

And when I use HttpWebRequester is sends following data which results in Code 400 rather then Code 200

```
POST https://plus.google.com/_/socialgraph/mutate/modifymemberships/?_reqid=1950158&rt=j HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
X-Same-Domain: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
Referer: https://plus.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/home/b,s/rt=h/ver=OeD97kiQfn8.en./sv=1/am=!iPoVWvyH1UcKPT9bc1pNSZLcSj8oHAelto24gJorhwk/d=1/
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: plus.google.com
Cookie: ULS=EgYKBBICZW4Yp_7k9wQ; SID=DQAAALYAAAAZuUVe6hDQbW__dA1Itrcz8thm2Ncxk5YFMfpeiKyr6Pps1Pu0ajmReczMDHKGnDpk3yrx7WFy-5QMOf0Fu4WiPVdUWcU_cLNfD7FhKtqmSmOgFiffTkyj8dg0bsTeahhrKR7j75rjU_eXqGnQI2qcJHOyk1cLEkWNaWyLRGeYDrsfAh6uzx4AI-1GtKbwwrE7UHsn_sUFG1DuwI_Ct_g9C2llFVVyQruvFnlmRE1xDE_ORwvnBYCrGQYjyt1blg8; HSID=AbkExs5EzrPodpoKx; SSID=A2y_-xD7iOhW9Y2HF; APISID=73YQ7BugDgjmMSdd/AgFF1ClZc0z-fpPGM; SAPISID=mT6qzvCACzlvDrg-/AN1ajSgZCB0R9xOmX
Content-Length: 216
Connection: Keep-Alive

a=%5b%5b%5b%225947b6d78a8231f3%22%5d%5d%5d&m=%5b%5b%5b%5bnull%2cnull%2c%22113690702042497323038%22%5d%2c%22Stephanie%20Parker%22%2c%5b%5d%5d%5d%5d&r=%5b%5b%5d%5d&at=AObGSAg06IXl5iYSceecKRc64xHVAB_GDw%3a1324806859000&
```

So any idea why this to similar requests have 2 different server response?

BTW I did check cookies and they are fine. I'm just puzzled on why my request would not work.

**UPDATE** Request Code added

```
webRequest_ = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Params.URL);

webRequest_.Method = "POST";
//webRequest_.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://plus.google.com", false);
webRequest_.UserAgent = Params.UserAgent;
webRequest_.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5");
webRequest_.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
webRequest_.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
webRequest_.KeepAlive = true;
webRequest_.Headers.Add("X-Same-Domain", "1");
webRequest_.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
webRequest_.Referer = "https://plus.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/home/b,s/rt=h/ver=OeD97kiQfn8.en./sv=1/am=!iPoVWvyH1UcKPT9bc1pNSZLcSj8oHAelto24gJorhwk/d=1/";
webRequest_.CookieContainer = Params.Cookie;
webRequest_.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
webRequest_.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

var sp = webRequest_.ServicePoint;
var prop = sp.GetType().GetProperty("HttpBehaviour", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
prop.SetValue(sp, (byte)0, null);

var parameters = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var key in Params.Params)
{
    parameters.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key.ToString()),
       HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Params.Params[key.ToString()]).Replace("+","%20"));

}

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest_.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(parameters.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Its not really enough info but if i were you i would get in there with fiddler and start making requests with the original request and change the fields 1 by 1 to make it look like your request until you see the point it breaks

Comment: Why don't you use the Google+ API?

Comment: The requests are not at all the same. Firstly, you miss some cookies in the second request, e.g. ID. Then, you are posting over https so the request is supposed to be encrypted with the public key of the site. And thirdly, I would really doubt that all values stay the same between requests.

Comment: How can we know what's wrong with your code when you don't show any code at all? You also might tell us what part of the headers is wrong.

Comment: @Luke McGregor I got top request from fiddler and fiddled with cookies and fields they all looks ok.

Comment: @SLaks becase google API allows only read access

Comment: @Pencho Ilchev Yes cookie do differ but it does pass authentication. Also WebReqest object does ssl transparently as far as I can tell

Comment: @John Saunders As I have mention in my question that top request returns Http code 200 and second 400 and if I knew which header breaks the request I would've posted the question in the first place.

Comment: The question is whether the two requests themselves are the same or different, not whether the responses are different.

Comment: @John Saunders The question is if there is anything particular that I missing or doing wrong when posting this request.

Comment: Yes, you're doing something wrong: you haven't posted any code!

Comment: @Tim did you try modifying the first request to look more like the second? ie removing the host field, accept-encoding ect

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Yes I tried, host present in both request just in a different order

Comment: @JohnSaunders Just added the code.

Comment: @Tim did you try the second request as it stands?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Yes I did it returns 400 which is error

Comment: *Grasping at straws* is it possible that in your post payload, you have the Hex numbers encoded as lowercase which is causing the problem?

Comment: Also, try removing the ampersand from the end of your post payload - even though the browser request also has it.

Comment: @feroze Yes tried that did not help. but I think I have figured out what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive testing I have figured out that problem is not in a header but rather in the data that gets posted, particularly in "at" parameter which is stands for session Id. After successfully generation session id it did work like a charm.

Comment: Can you share how you generated the session id?